# Applying Newton's law on spring mass system - sign problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conventions, spring

I understand that restoring force of the spring on mass is $-kx$.

When we apply newtons second law in SHM of spring mass,

Only force on the mass is the spring restoring force,

that is, Fnet= -kx.

We know, Fnet = -ma( minus since acceleration is negative if x is positive).

So, -kx = -ma

Thus, kx = ma

and a= kx/m( not -kx/m)

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Don’t confuse yourself! $F\ne-ma$.

In fact, $F=+ma$ per Newton’s second law. In this case, also $F=-kx$. Therefore, $ma=-kx$, indicating that the acceleration is in the opposite direction of the displacement (i.e. the spring provides a restoring force).